# Informatica Expression Convert String to Date

Tags: expression, informatica-powercenter

I need to convert a string to a date so I can do a compare with what is in my column.  My statement is this:

```
Decode(IsNew, FALSE, 
  IIF (v_save_view_row_obsolete_day <> 
    TO_DATE('9999-12-31 00:00:00 AM','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
     '9999-12-31 00:00:00', v_save_view_row_obsolete_day))
```

When I validate I get this error:
[image: Error Image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified 24-hour format, so you don't need the `AM` meridian indicator in the converted date.

Alternatively, you could add `AM` to the format parameter of `TO_DATE`.

Comment: Thank you! I am glad for another set of eyes

Answer (score 1):

I think that this:

TO_DATE('9999-12-31 00:00:00 AM','YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),

should be this:

TO_DATE('9999-12-31 00:00:00 AM','YYYY-**MM**-DD HH24:MI:SS'),

MM instead of MON